# Draw lines to connect some points in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I have an array of point coordinates like,

```
Coordinates = [ x1 y1;
                x2 y2;
                x3 y3;
                x4 y4];
```

I would like to draw lines to connect these points.

For example, I would like to connect the point `(x1, y1)` to `(x2, y2)` and the point `(x3, y3)` to `(x4, y4)` and so on.

Would you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "join"?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Join"?

Comment: By join I mean connect them by line.

Answer (score 0):

Plain copy form the [plot](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html) documentation:

```
x = -pi:.1:pi;
y = sin(x);
plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

`plot([x1,x2],[y1,y2],  [x3,x4],[y3,y4])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i=1:no_of_elements

line([x(i),y(i)],[x(i+1),y(i+1)])

end
```

Answer (score 0):

As user3487733 said, but with a slight adjustment in the first line.

```
for I=1:2:no_of_elements
    line([x(I),y(I)],[x(I+1),y(I+1)])
end
```

user3487733's answer will connect `(x1,y1)` to `(x2,y2)` to `(x3,y3)` to `(x4,y4)`.
As I understand the question you want `(x1,y1)` to `(x2,y2)` and then `(x3,y3)` to `(x4,y4)`; i.e. `(x2,y2)` is not connected to `(x3,y3)`.